# what can I do if an application doesn't recognize horizontal scrolling?

Tags: mouse, logitech-mouse, ssms

I have a mouse with a horizontal scroll wheel (the MX Master by Logitech), but the horizontal scrolling is only recognized by some applications (e.g. Excel and Chrome).

Other applications (like SQL Server Management Studio, aka SSMS) don't appear to recognize the horizontal scroll. In this example SSMS has a "results" pane for the results of a query, which has a horizontal scrollbar, but the horizontal scroll wheel doesn't move it.

Is this something that the programmer of the application has to add support for? Or are there possibly some hacks that could let me build my own support? I am running Windows 7, incidentally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am also using the MX Master and ran into this issue.

### The Fix

Open up your Logitech Options software and from the "Mouse" panel, click the white circle over the Thumb Wheel Scroll. This will bring up behavior options. Inexplicably, changing the behavior to "Zoom In/Out" seems to fix this horizontal scrolling issue (at least, I can confirm this for SSMS.)

Try this out for other applications -- if your horizontal scrolling breaks, elsewhere, try using the Application Specific settings to only change the behavior in your desired application.

Happy Scrolling!

Comment: Nice! Thanks for posting, this also works for me. It's a shame that the scrolling is a bit slow for SSMS, even after adjusting the sensitivity to its highest amount. But it's better than nothing.

Comment: wow this works for me too

Comment: This worked for VSCode.  I can now horizontally scroll through files and tabs.

Comment: The problem is still there and this works for Logitech M720 too.

Answer (score 5):

The "fix" that worked for me, after trying hundreds of things -> **Uninstall** *LogiTech Options*.

Answer (score 2):

Hold `Ctrl` + `Vertical Scroll`. That offers more sensitivity and a smoother scrolling experience, SSMS in particular.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with horizontal scrolling in PDF-XChange-Viewer. "Horizontal scroll" did not work, and Zoom in/Out did not work either. The later did exactly what it said: zooming in and out.

Remapping the key-strokes separately solved the problem. Settings go as the following:

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the keystroke is no longer available in Logitech Options, at least not for my MX Master 2S. Can anyone confirm this for new mice (or older ones with the tilt wheel?

Answer (score 2):

In my case Logitech software update didn't fix the problem.

So I found a little trick to fix (temporarily) the problem. When your horizontal scroll doesn't work on **VScode** or other apps. Open your Chrome browser (or any browser) use the *side wheel* then click anywhere on your browser. Back to your **VScode** then use the *side wheel* once again.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I accidentally fount this same solution, though different apps, I suspect it may be that somehow if the horizontal scroll gets locked by "A" then it wont work in "B". By returning to "A" and scrolling there then unhooks it so it then works in "B". I'm uncertain to what hooks it in "A" but whatever it is doesn't always do this.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was an old version of Options that was installed automatically. After manual update to the latest Options build horizontal scrolling was fixed.

But this only worked for Edge and some other apps. There are still some apps that do not respond properly to horizontal scrolling. That is very sad for a device like Master MX 2S.